# Is it possible to determine whether you are in the last row of a css-defined column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the new css-style column to break a single ul into multiple columns. I wish to select the last element in each column with javascript or CSS.

html:

```
<ul>
  <li />
  <li />
  <li><h4 /></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul{
   column-count: 6;
}
```

Sometimes the line-items with h4:s in them end up as the last item of the row, being orphans.  I would like to solve this, and have been looking at two alternatives.

Using the css orphan property, but due to the markup I don't think it will work at all and It is not unsupported in Firefox and Safari, support is not a must but would be nice.

Adding some top-margin/padding to any h4 that is at the end of a column, but I don't know how to select them, either with css or javascript/jquery. I would prefer keeping the markup, as it is, but if it's not possible, I can change it.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understandig what you need to select. Is it the last li?

Comment: Updated for clarity!

Comment: @KristofferNolgren I've posted another answer, check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pqse3er1/

Comment: whether not weather.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns in CSS aren't content aware. The only two properties related to columns which can help you in a way are column-fill (which only works in firefox) and break-inside.

Column-fill will distribute the contents through the columns based on the height of the container.

Page-break will do for columns what clear does for floats, stopping elements from getting stuck between columns. It has different syntaxes across browsers.

```
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
          page-break-inside: avoid; /* Firefox */
               break-inside: avoid; /* IE 10+ */
```

But anyway, columns are more helpful when you have a container with text and want to divide it in columns without any extra markup. Since you are using li and don't have just a text inside a div, I would suggest you to use floats to achieve the multi column layout you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the :last-child selector for selecting the last LI element.

```
    li:last-child{color:red;}
```

Comment: it's not the last element in ul, it's the last item in the column

Comment: This is not an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

You question is unclear.

If you want to know if your element (ex. `h4`) is in the last `li` than use CSS:

```
ul li:last-of-type h4
```

If you want to know this in JS but withou use of pseudoselector than you can use:

```
$(function () {
    var $li = $('ul > li'),
        count = $li.length - 1,
        cssClass = 'last';

    $li.eq(count).addClass(cssClass);;
});
```

And from here use CSS `ul li.last h4`

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwuzgm08/2/

Comment: it's not the last element, it's the last item in the column.

Comment: So remove h4 and you will select last column lawl. Anyway added jQuery solution

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can remove the orphan h4 tag from your html. Below is the simple scripts that does the same.

```
$('h4').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.html().replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0)
        $this.remove();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to select last element in each column (assuming `li` is an column) you can use following CSS

```
ul > li h4:last-of-type
```

or jQuery:

```
$('ul > li h4:last-of-type')
```

Providing fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pqse3er1/1/

Comment: it's not the last element in ul, it's the last item in the column

Comment: Column is a css-property that brakes content into columns.

Comment: It's not possible. @nunopolonia gave you an answer, you shall accept it. -1 for unclear question.